# iOS: Unable to access instance methods inside a C-class

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, callback

I dont think I've understood C well enough.

In my codes, added a call back method.

And inside the method, I want to be able call a method that beings to the instance. I tried `[self methodName]`  but I'm told 'self is an undeclared identifier`.

**Added code snippets**:

```
@implementation TheClass


static void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
                                       void                      *inUserData,
                                       AudioSessionPropertyID    inPropertyID,
                                       UInt32                    inPropertyValueSize,
                                       const void                *inPropertyValue) 
{

    .
    .
     //trying to call a instance method of TheClass here.
}
```

Comment: I meant C. I wrote C code inside an Objective-C class.

Comment: Is you callback a static function? If it is, it's not aware of your class. You might be able to send your class to the callback when you define it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `self` in a plain C function, it doesn't belong to any Objective-C instance (that's the difference between a function and a method).

For callbacks that are supposed to interact with Objective-C, you would usually pass a pointer to your object when you set up the callback. In this case, `inUserData` is probably something that you can set yourself when registering the callback.

Comment: hi thank you! i realize i did passed in `self` when setting up property listener. This is the first time I'm working with a C class, great to have got it working!

Answer (score 0):

In your question, the syntax you are using is not C, but objective-C. Are you attempting to use objective-C? If so, self is a keyword, not an identifier. The compiler clearly thinks your code is C, not Objective-C. Does your source file have a .m file extension?